# Custom confirm android dialog does not work

Tags: java, android

I am learning android and I need to create a global custom android confirm dialog to be used across the entire app but does not work. First the UI of the application looks like this image
[image]
The buttons looks small and dont know what am doing wrong.
Here is my layout xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"


    android:orientation="vertical"


    android:layout_marginRight="25dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
    android:background="@drawable/alert_bg">

    <TextView
        android:textColor="@color/colorStandardBlack"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/text_view_confirm"
        android:text="@string/confirm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     <LinearLayout
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:id="@+id/liner_confirm"
        android:background="@color/chrome_bg"

        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>

    <TextView

        android:textColor="@color/colorStandardBlack"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:id="@+id/text_view_confirm_message"
        android:text="Lorem ipskljsdf kfjsda fkdlsja fs fdsfdsfsdfsdfsdf fsfsdfsdffdf sfsdf fksjffska fdjslkfjsdlfjslfjsdkl fksdfjklsdjfklsd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        <Button
            style="@style/Button_With_Radius"
            android:background="#fdcb6e"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            style="@style/Button_With_Radius"
            android:background="#0984e3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/confirm"
            android:textAllCaps="true"

            android:id="@+id/button_confirm"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the style for the buttons

```
<style name="Button_With_Radius">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/primary_round_with_radius</item>
    </style>
```

here is primary_round_with_radius.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </shape>
```

Now on the other end of java the function returns false all times even if I click confirm.
Here is my java code.

```
static boolean yes_no;
    public static boolean confirmAction(final Context context,String message)
    {
        yes_no=false;//if declared here it requesting to be final but final cannot be intialized in a inner class
        final Dialog dialogView=getCustomDialog(context,R.layout.custom_confirm_dialog);
        dialogView.show();
        Button confirm=dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button_confirm);
        Button cancel=dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);
        TextView textView=dialogView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_confirm_message);
        textView.setText(message);
        confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                yes_no=true;
                dialogView.dismiss();
           
            


            }
        });

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              yes_no=false;
                dialogView.dismiss();
              


            }
        });

        return yes_no;
    }
    
       public static Dialog getCustomDialog(Context context, int layout_id)
    {
        Dialog dialog= new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);

        if ( dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing() ){
            dialog.cancel();
        }

        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(layout_id);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        return dialog;
    }
```

and here is how am trying to use my custom dialog

boolean yes=AppUtil.confirmAction(this,"Are you sure you wish to do this?");
Toast.makeText(this,""+yes,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//this always return false
and here is alert bg xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#fff" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Can you please share the remaining resources, used inside this...  I'am trying to figure out the issue but their is some resources are missing...

Comment: @hafiza what resources do u need?

Comment: alert_bg is missing

Comment: @hafiza I have included

Comment: I figured out, first of all I'm not getting Button Size issue, But the way you are implementing is not correct. First you are getting response then you are entering response so every time you're getting Initialized response.

Comment: @hafiza have you tried that code? Why am I getting button resize issues?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your CODE, I am not getting that BUTTON SIZE issue :

PLEASE TRY TO get response by using interfaces:
Hopefully this link will help you,

If getting any issue revert back to me, I'll explain.

[How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)

[image]

Use below Color Codes:

and Change Background Colors to these:

```
<color name="purple">#FF6200EE</color>
<color name="teal">#FF018786</color>
<color name="black">#FF000000</color>
```

***To Make Reusable Dialog:***

Create a separate Interface Class called: DialogClickListener.java
And add the following code

```
public interface DialogClickListener {
     public void onPositiveButtonClick();
     public void onNegativeButtonClick();
}
```

Create another Class Called ConfirmDialog.java that should implement the click listener:

```
public class ConfirmDialog extends Dialog implements
    android.view.View.OnClickListener {

}
```

Now In this Class Add the following Code:

```
 public class ConfirmDialog extends Dialog implements
    android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    public Activity activity;
    private DialogClickListener listener;
    public Button yes, no;

    public ConfirmDialog(Activity activity, DialogClickListener listener) {
        super(activity);
        this.activity = activity;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_confirm);
        yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
        no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_no);

        yes.setOnClickListener(this);
        no.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_yes:
                listener.onPositiveButtonClick();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_no:
                listener.onNegativeButtonClick();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

**Dialog Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="40dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_dia"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Please explain your action here"
        android:textColor="@color/theme_blue"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_yes"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:text="@string/continue_text"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_no"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Usage**

Any Class where you want to use this Dialog, just implement this Listener that we created and implement the methods and simply declare dialog and show.

**Sample Code**

```
public class TryActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DialogClickListener {

    LanguageConfirmDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_try);

        dialog = new LanguageConfirmDialog(TryActivity.this, this);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPositiveButtonClick() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Yes Tapped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNegativeButtonClick() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cancel Tapped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Demo Images:**

[image]

[image]

Done

Comment: why is my code not working then? I cant understand

Comment: On which device you're testing?, try to change you color to the one that I will update in answer.

Comment: Am using simulator

Comment: I'm using real device.

Comment: if you want to use Custom Reusable Dialog, create separate class of Dialog, and If you're interested to get more from Me, I'll add remaining Explanation in Answer.

Comment: you are right on real device button are ok. How do I listen for yes or no confirm dialog on click?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230062/discussion-between-hafiza-and-nemuga-dev).

Comment: can you help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66796385/how-to-consume-spring-boot-websocket-stomp-api-in-android-app

Comment: @NemugaDev Sorry, I don't have any experience of Spring/Spring boot.

Comment: I needed to create a real time chat app using websocket. Any idea on how I implement it

Answer (score 1):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    showDialog { isConfirmed: Boolean ->  
        if(isConfirmed){
            // write your logic 
        }else{
            // write your logic  
        }
    }
}

private fun showDialog(onConfirmedDialogClicked: (isConfirmed: Boolean) -> Unit) {
    val dialog = Dialog(this)
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout)
    val buttonConfirm = dialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnConfirm)
    val buttonCancel = dialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_cancel)
    buttonCancel.setOnClickListener { 
        dialog.dismiss()
        onConfirmedDialogClicked.invoke(false)
    }
    buttonConfirm.setOnClickListener {
        dialog.dismiss()
        onConfirmedDialogClicked.invoke(true)
    }
    dialog.show()
}
```

}

Here is my simple code in Kotlin, your issue is the **confirmAction** function return false immediately before confirm button was clicked. You have to use interface instead.

Here is the java code version:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    showDialog(new OnConfirmDialogClicked() {
        @Override
        public void onDialogButtonClicked(Boolean isConfirmed) {
            if(isConfirmed){
                // write your logic
            }else{
                // write your logic
            }
        }
    });
}

private void showDialog(OnConfirmDialogClicked onConfirmDialogClicked){
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
    Button btnConfirm = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);
    Button btnCancel = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    btnConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            onConfirmDialogClicked.onDialogButtonClicked(true);
        }
    });
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            onConfirmDialogClicked.onDialogButtonClicked(false);
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
    
}
interface OnConfirmDialogClicked{
    void onDialogButtonClicked(Boolean isConfirmed);
}
```

}

Comment: Dont know kotlin How would I do that in java